# Data Type of holding multiple Data

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I want an datatype which can hold an Integer and Char.

```
private Int32[] XCordinates = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
private Char[] yCordinates = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J' };
```

and I want result something like this

```
A0
A1
A2
A3
A4 and so on.... upto 
J8
J9
```

Now which data type should I use for the fastest performance and data retrieval from lets Say "H6" entry.

1. Dictionaries are out of equation since they don't allow multiple keys
2. ArrayList could be used but it can store only *one* type of object and required boxing/unboxing.

or I can use

```
List<KeyValuePair<Char, Int32>> myKVPList = new List<KeyValuePair<Char, Int32>>();
foreach (Char yValue in yCordinates)
{
   foreach (Int32 xValue in XCordinates)
   {
       myKVPList.Add(new KeyValuePair<Char, Int32>(yValue, xValue));
    }
 }
```

but List are slowest in accessing data as compared to arrays, Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what problem you want to solve, but wouldn't a "datatype which can hold an Integer and Char" technically be: `public struct MyXY { public char X; public int Y; public override string ToString() { return X + Y.ToString(); } }`? And then you can have an array of that like `var a = new MyXY[length]`.

Comment: I reject your premise that lists are slower in accessing data than arrays.  They are not, at least not by any meaningful amount.  That difference is almost certainly not enough to be a problem in your program.

Comment: Performance of retrieval depends on _kind_ of retrieval. Do you just want to sequentially traverse the elements and is order important? Do you want to access an individual element and how (by index or by key value)? Do you need to add the elements later? Etc, etc...

Comment: Yes, I want Random Access in my data type, I mentioned in my question "Data retrieval from lets Say "H6" entry", and yes elements could be added/updated later as well.

Comment: You were ambiguous about that. Retrieval from "H6" could have just as easily been key-based, not random. You also mentioned dictionary, which is almost, but not exactly "random". Anyhow, it looks like you need a `List<T>` (which is implemented on top of array, but can "stretch"), or possibly `LinkedList<T>` depending on _where_ you want to add new elements. Your assertion about `ArrayList` performance is right, but your assertion about `List<T>` performance is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET framework 3.5 includes a special LINQ [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class.

```
var lookup = (from x in yCordinates
             from y in XCordinates
             select new{x, y}).ToLookup(xy => xy.x, xy => xy.y);

foreach(var xy in lookup)
    Console.WriteLine("x:{0} y-values:{1}", xy.Key, string.Join(",", xy.Select(y => y)));
```

Result:

```
x:A y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:B y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:C y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:D y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:E y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:F y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:G y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:H y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:I y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x:J y-values:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` is similar to a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maps keys to single values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` maps keys to collections of values.

It's drawbacks are:

- you cant just create a Lookup object since there is no public constructor, its only available using the `.ToLookup` method
- you cannot edit it once it has been created, no Add or Remove etc.

As a side note, you can query a lookup (via the indexer) on a key that doesn't exist, and you'll get an empty sequence. Do the same with a dictionary and you'll get an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, That lookup solves my purpuse, however what variable type is this lookup ? If I do this...

 Lookup<Char, Int32> lookup = (from x in yCordinates
                          from y in XCordinates
                          select new { x, y }).ToLookup(xy => xy.x, xy => xy.y);

It gives me an error that Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.ILookup<char,int>' to 'System.Linq.Lookup<char,int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 

Actually I have to return this "lookup" from another function so I want it to make it as a member field.

Comment: @Pankaj: It is a `ILookup<char, int>`. The type `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` implements the `ILookup<TKey, TElement>` interface which `ToLookup` returns. I would recommend to use the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the byte representation of characters and numbers then formatt them:

```
        //values from 48-57 are 0 to 9,65-90 uppercase letters,97-122 lowercase letters
        byte[] ba = new byte[] { 65, 49, 70, 52, 88, 55 };

        for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i += 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}",(char)ba[i],(char)ba[i + 1]));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

If you really dont want to use dictionary you can also try just string representation:

```
            string[] vals = new string[] { "A122", "C67", "T8" };
            foreach (var item in vals)
            {
                //this is just to show you can convert to an int because if its
                //one letter and numbers you know index 1 of string will be
                //the start of the number representation.
                int count = int.Parse(item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1));
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.Substring(0, 1), item.Substring(1, item.Length - 1));
            }
```